# odoo 11 accounting fiscal periods

Tags: odoo, accounting, odoo-11

i just installed odoo 11 CE and managed to get the accounting features by activating in the user settings. However the most important functions to create fiscal periods and to close a fiscal year properly seems to be completely missing.

If this is the case and this is only available in the enterprise version the CE version becomes pretty much useless for accounting.

Thanks for any hint
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Peter,

In odoo 11 (and I think since odoo 9) there are not Fiscal Periods anymore. The way to act is to create Date Ranges, that are multi propose ranges to use anywhere.

Conceptually there is not a closing of the fiscal year, but you can filter all your data by Date Ranges and make all your reporting based on this new model.

This seems to be a more flexible and powerful tool, but here is the bad news. One basic thing I think Odoo has missed out is the functionality of close a period or, in other words, to prevent of creating journal entries to the users when they are in a period. You have to use locking dates. This functionality is half implemented but it is very blocking. After the locking date, you cannot register payments because they are creating journal entries after the blocking date. I have searched a lot and I have found this [PR](https://github.com/OCA/OCB/pull/699#issuecomment-375773797) in the OCA related with a set of functionalities to solve all this scenario.

Hope it helps to give you a scope of the functionality and limitations.

Cheers,

Pere

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the fiscal year end in Odoo by entering the Fiscal year last day, and specifying locking status as below:

[image: Fiscal Year]

After this, there is no need to make a 'physical closure' for the fiscal year.

> In Odoo there is no need to do a specific year end closing entry in
>   order to close out income statement accounts. The reports are created
>   in real-time, meaning that the Income statement corresponds directly
>   with the year-end date you specify in Odoo.

Reference:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/11.0/accounting/others/adviser/fiscalyear.html

Answer (score 0):

From Odoo 11, closing of fiscal years happen automatically at designated year end i.e balances of P&L accounts are zeroed out and the net is carried forward in the Balance sheet. All you need to do is to decide how to allocate the current year earning.